# how i remove interaction in PageViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uipageviewcontroller

the view which has the dot (green UIView) I need not leave the User use the drag and move or could put the dot in the view of the image. someone could help me with one of the two solutions?

[IMAGE APP](http://postimg.org/image/omc3z23kp/)

CODE:

```
-(void) initWithLit {

    _pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Felipe"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png",@"page2.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    //[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.pageViewController];

    [self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:navigationController ];
    [self.mm_drawerController closeDrawerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;    
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.btnOK.hidden = FALSE;


    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you intend to build a tutorial page. If you want to add dynamic dots you just need to add UIPageControl element which you can check it out here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/index.html

It is easy to use. You can find lots of example out there.